# Misunderstanding of Nyquist sampling theorem and minimum sampling rate

Tags: sampling, dft, nyquist, time-frequency, time-domain

I sample my time-domain (TD) signal using a distance between time-samples of $\delta = (t_{max} - t_{min}) / N_t$, where $N_t$ is the number of samples taken. The sampling rate is $1 / \delta$.
I have read 10's of lectures about DFT, but it seems I still don't understand the basics.

I know the sampling theorem: if the signal is bandwidth limited to $f_c$, that is, its FT is 0 for any $f$ NOT in the interval $[- f_c, ..., f_c]$, the signal can be perfectly reconstructed from its discrete samples taken at a rate $\delta = 1 / (2 * f_c)$, or higher.

I also know the Nyquist criterion: I need to sample my time domain signal at a rate which is at least twice the value of the maximum frequency present in the signal. That would be $1/\delta > 2 * f_{max}$.

According to my understanding of the accepted answer from here: [Discrete inverse Fourier transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53117/discrete-inverse-fourier-transform), it seems I need to sample at a rate $ 1/\delta > f_{max}$, where $f_{max}$ is the highest frequency present in the signal.

What I am missing, the above two facts seem different for me, by a factor of 2.

Starting from page 2 of these notes, it seems that the condition from the DSP answer above is in agreement with both TD->FD sampling theorem and also with FD->TD sampling theorem. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-341-discrete-time-signal-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec15.pdf. The second picture of the diagram shown on page 2 makes sense to me visually: in order to avoid folding back to the 1st Nyquist zone, given that the length of the base of any of the triangles is $\Omega_0$, then $\Omega_0 / 2$ (RHS of the center triangle)  + $\Omega_0 / 2$ (LHS of the 1st triangle to the right of the center triangle) < $ 2\pi / (\Delta T)$ (the center of the 1st triangle to the right of the center triangle).

**My question is probably more general**:

When designing the input 1D vector of length $N_t$ for a FFT algorithm for computing a direct discrete FT, what shall I look for, if we consider that I have infinite computational power (hypothetically)?
Do I just need to make sure that the sampling rate is twice the bandwidth of the signal, where the bandwidth is $f_{max} - f_{min}$? I.e. only to respect the Nyquist criterion?

Answer (score 2):

If the signal is complex, then $1/\delta > f_{max}$ with consideration to the bins of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) extending from $k=0 \ldots N-1$ since the Discrete Fourier Transform will be unique in that case from bin $0$ to bin $N-1$. If the signal is real, then the DFT will be Hermitian symmetric, so we may only consider bins $0$ to $(N-1)/2$ since bins $(N-1)/2$ to $N-1$ will be the complex conjugate of bins$1$ to $(N-1/2)$. For example, with $N$ odd and a real signal, $k_1 = k^*_{N-1}$, $k_2 = k^*_{N-2}$, etc. This may lead one to state that $f_{max}$ is less than $(N-1)/2$ for that case.

In general, the Nyquist sampling theorem is to sample complex baseband signals extending from $-B/2$ to $+B/2$ at a sampling rate greater than $B$. When you consider the DFT bins can equally represent signals from DC to (nearly) the sampling rate $f_s$ (since for $N$ bins for $k$ from  $0$ to $N-1$, bin $N$ would represent the sampling rate $f_s$) or equivalently (nearly) $-f_s/2$ to $+f_s/2$ the above is not in conflict with the Nyquist sampling theorem.

Comment: Thank you. One thing, I am sorry if it's correct, but shouldn't it be "complex signals extending from -B/2 to B/2 at a sampling rate greater than B?" and not 2B? So that it corresponds to what you said in the first paragraph about the complex signals?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I think you got it.

Comment: Your first paragraph leads to the conclusion that: Having $\Delta = (t_{max} - t_{min}) / N$, for complex signals I need that $1/\Delta > f_{max}$ and for real signals I need that $(1/\Delta) + (1/(t_{max} - t_{min})) > 2 \times f_{max}$ ?

Comment: Also, having defined $\Delta = (t_{max} - t_{min}) / N$, I believe the last sentence of your 1st paragraph shall read: "This may lead one to state that $f_{max}$ is less than $(N-1) / (2 \times (t_{max} - t_{min}))$". Right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your statement of the Nyquist sampling theorem only works for infinite length signals.  If N is finite, then you need to sample **above** twice the highest spectrum frequency present by some amount.

That's because any finite length window has infinite support in the frequency domain.  Same with any finite length reconstruction or anti-aliasing filter.  Thus, the windowing cause by a finite length of sampling will spread your signal's spectrum. Beyond the edges of your supposed band-limit.

So you have to sample at a rate at or above 2X the frequency where the window's stopband energy goes below your desired noise floor.  Which will never be zero even with "perfect" reconstruction for a finite length of samples (unless assumed to be perfectly periodically extended to beyond the lifetime of the known universe.)

Comment: Hello, isn't this phrase: "you need to sample above twice the highest spectrum frequency present" in contradiction with: "So you have to sample at a rate at or above the frequency where the window's stopband energy goes below your desired noise floor" ? Am I missing something? Is it twice (2x) the highest spectrum frequency or 1x the highest spectrum frequency? Thanks

Comment: more than 2x the highest spectrum frequency